Is every linear relation on $\mathbb{C}^2\times \mathbb{C}^2$ represented by two matrices?
Let us consider the following definition.
Definition. Let $H_1,H_2$ be Hilbert spaces. A linear subspace $D$ of $H_1\oplus H_2$ is called a linear relation from $H_1$ to $H_2$.
Now, let $H_1=H_2=\mathbb{C^2}$. It is easy to show that for $A,B\in M_{2}(\mathbb{C})$ the set
$$D_{A,B}=\left\{(z,w)\in\mathbb{C^2}\oplus\mathbb{C^2}:Az=Bw\right\}$$
is a linear relation form $\mathbb{C^2}$ to $\mathbb{C^2}$. However, I would like to know if for every linear relation $D$ from $\mathbb{C^2}$ to $\mathbb{C^2}$ there exist matrices $A,B\in M_2(\mathbb{C^2})$ such that $D=D_{A,B}$ (i.e., if $D$ can be represeted by two matrices). If it is not true, can you construct an explicit example?
I will apreciate your help.

A subspace of $\Bbb C^2\oplus\Bbb C^2$ is the kernel of a $4\times k$ matrix for some $0\le k\le 4$. Your $D_{A,B}$ is a subspace where necessarily $k=2$ and the matrix is of the form $\begin{bmatrix} A&-B\end{bmatrix}$. So the subspace has dimension $\ge 2$. So take any subspace of dimension $\le 1$.

Great! This means that if $D_{A,B}$ is defined for $A,B\in M_{k\times 2}(\mathbb{C})$ with $0\leq k\leq 4$, then the statement would be true?

Yes, sure. Just understand why (prove that) every subspace is the kernel of some matrix.
